# Counting words in string with c

Tags: c, count

`the push to vaccinate children has taken on fresh urgency amid concerns that the new omicron variant of the virus       first identified in southern africa and hong kong in late november     will spread quickly in the united states causing a surge in infections already back on the rise from the easily transmitted delta variant             given the pervasiveness of delta and prospects of new variants spreading in the united states                 having as much immunity in the population as possible is critical      said   dr   amesh adalja senior scholar at the    johns hopkins    center    for   health security`

This is my assignment:

- replace multiple spaces to one space between words and delete unnecessary spaces at the beginning and the end.
- count the words
- print edited string
- dont use a new string, just edit.

I can't find problem. It should count the words but it can not do. Help me, please.

```
//Counting words program C
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5000

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char text[N];
    
    int k, d, leng, spacecount = 0;
    int m, j, z, i, p, n;

    if ((fp = fopen("soru.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Dosya acma hatasi!");
        return 1;
    }
    
    fgets(text, N - 1, fp);
    
    while (k < N && text[k] != '\0') {
        leng++;
        k++;
    }
    
    z = leng;
    
    for (i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        if (i = 0 && text[i] == ' ') {
            z--;
            for (m = 0; m < leng; m++) {
                text[m] = text[m + 1];
            }
            i--;
            text[z] == '\0';
        } else
        if (text[i] ==' ' && text[i + 1] == ' ') {
            z--;
            for (j = i; j < leng; j++) {
                text[j + 1] = text[j + 2];
            }
            i--;
            text[z] == '\0';
        } else
        if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i + 1] == '\0') {
            z--;
            for (j = i; j < leng; j++) {
                text[j] = text[j + 1];
            }
            i--;
            text[z] == '\0';
        } else
        if (text[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (text[d] != '\0') {
        if (text[d] == ' ') 
            spacecount++;
        d++;
    }
        
    printf("kelime sayisi: %d" , spacecount + 1);
    printf("\n cikti:%s ", text);
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### I can't find problem. It should count the word but it can not do. Help me, please

```
for(i=0; i < leng; i++) {

    if(i=0 && text[i]== ' '){

        z--;
        for(m=0; m< leng; m++ ){

        text[m] = text [m+1];}
        i--;

        }

    else if(1<i<z && text[i] ==' ' && text[i+1] == ' ' ){
        z--;
        for(j=i; j<leng ; j++) {

        text[j+1] = text [j+2];}
        i--;

        } 

    else if(i=z && text[i] ==' ' && text[i+1] == '\0' ){
        z--;
        for(j=i; j<leng ; j++) {

        text[j] = text [j+1];    }
        i--;

        }

},// I think problem in here. Endless loop
```

Comment: Your program only needs one loop.  I suggest having one pointer for reading from the input string and one pointer for writing to the result string.  (The input and result strings can be the same string because your read pointer will move forward at least as fast as the write pointer.)  Then just do *one* loop that iterates through each character of the input.

Comment: Thank you but i dont understand, i am junior in c. can you explain with code?

Comment: Please reduce the shown code to a [mre] of your attempt to do what you ask about, i.e. counting words. Then describe how exactly it fails. Crash? No output? Wrong output? Endless loop? What is the output you get? What is the output you want? In which part of your code does the value of your counter start to be wrong?

Comment: @BATUHAN: Note that you can [edit] your question in order to add or replace code.

Comment: In first for  loop which is endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too complicated. You can solve the problem with 2 index variables: one to read the characters from the input line, one to write the relevant characters into the same buffer.

You would keep track of the previous character, starting with space, and detect the beginning of words as the current character is not a space following a space. You would thus count the words and only output a space before each word except the first on a line.

Here is a modified version:

```
//Counting words program C
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5000

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char text[N];
    int total_words = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen("soru.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Dosya açma hatası!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(text, N, fp) != NULL) {
        int len = strlen(text);
        int word_count = 0;
        char c, lastc = ' ';
        int i, j;

        // strip the trailing newline
        if (len > 0 && text[len - 1] == '\n') {
            text[--len] == '\0';
        }
        for (i = j = 0; i < len; i++) {
            c = text[i];
            if (c != ' ') {
                if (lastc == ' ') {
                    if (word_count > 0) {
                        // output a space between words
                        text[j++] = ' ';
                    }
                    word_count++;
                }
                text[j++] = c; // copy the non space character
            }
            lastc = c;
        }
        text[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
        printf("kelime sayısı: %d\n", word_count);
        printf("çıktı: %s\n", text);
        total_words += word_count;
    }           
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\ntoplam kelime sayısı: %d\n", total_words);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note a silly bug in your code: `if (i = 0 && text[i] == ' ')` is parsed as `if ((i = (0 && (text[i] == ' '))) != 0)` which is always false and sets `i` to the value `0`.  C expression syntax is very powerful but somewhat error prone and confusing. I advise you to use `-Wall` or `-Weverything` as a compiler option to let the compiler warn about potential mistakes.

Similarly, you should not write `if (1<i<z && ...`: `1<i<z` is parsed as `1<(i<z)` which is always false. You must write `1 < i && i < z` or more idiomatically `i > 1 && i < z`